# Extrapolating with IDW (Feature Classes) in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, interpolation, arcgis-pro, masking, inverse-distance-weighted

I have been struggling to *extrapolate* beyond the extent of the point features input into the IDW tool of ArcGIS Pro.

I *believe* IDW interpolation is the method for me, i just need the process to extend beyond the input points slightly to fit a bigger area.

Specifying a mask in the environment settings seems only to clip the same extent (that is that of the input points), to the mask.

Comment: In the environment option you can define "processing extent" and then in the "raster analysis" choose your mask too. In this way the IDW will result in what you need. I just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you cannot extrapolate using IDW interpolation. Spline was a sufficient substitute and can be extrapolated.